# How to count the total no. of key in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

How to count the no.of keys in python dictionary?

I have this dictionary.

```
{'Bob':21,
 'Alice':22,
 'Bob':20,
 'john':34,
 'Rita':34,
 'paul':32,
 'Bob':13,
 'Alice':33}
```

Can anyone help me to write a function to count the number of keys ?
Ex:

```
# Bob-3
# Alice-2
```

Comment: That dictionary is not possible in Python, a dictionary cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: Can anyone give me answer

Comment: @Vivan You had your answer: that is not possible, the count of a key will always be either 1 or 0

Comment: Try to print your dictionary, you will see that each key is unique.